# I am getting an error in using Selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I tried using selenium for building a program but it just does not support web driver. I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\records\sel.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well it quite literally tells you where to go: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home,

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you need to install `chrome` and `chromedriver`.

for debian linux:

```
apt install chromium
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo cp chromedriver /usr/bin/
```